# Any living teachers claim to be able to attain vajrasamadhi?

Tags: mahayana, samadhi, gurus

Are there any living teachers who claim to be able to attain vajrasamadhi? Apologies if *looking for a guru* questions are off-topic here. Is there any way to verify if they have done so, according to the sutras etc.?

Answer (score 1):

vajrasamadhi translates as "adamantine absorption"(http://www.chinabuddhismencyclopedia.com/en/index.php?title=Vajrasamadhi). as (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vajrasamadhi-sutra). According to buddhist scholar Buswell, the Vajrasamadhi-sutra is regarded to be an "apocryphal scripture". The problem with Buddhism is that practitioners are not recommended to speak about their different types of samadhi experience in public cause it can lead you to unskilled clinging to such experience. Try visit local Chan/Zen centres and ask sensei about it.